# Write each unique file system right on a new line | PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am creating a PowerShell script that writes the permissions enabled on all of the folders within a directory to a CSV file for reporting purposes. A requirement for this report is that file system permissions must each be on a separate row, instead of all on one line (which my code currently does). For example, currently these permissions appear like this:

```
C:/temp-folder_123 (column) ReadData- ExecuteFile- Synchronize
```

but I want it to be formatted like this:

```
C:/temp-folder_123 (column) ReadData
C:/temp-folder_123 (column) ExecuteFile
C:/temp-folder_123 (column) Synchronize
```

Here's my code:

```
foreach ($access_right in $acl.Access) 
{
if ( ($access_right.FileSystemRights -notmatch $exclude_filesystem_rightss_regex) ) 
{
$file_stream_output.WriteLine(('{0}, {1}, {2}' -f $directory.FullName, $access_right.IdentityReference, ($access_right.FileSystemRights -replace ",","-" )))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To split the .FileSystemRights you'll have to iterate over them with another ForEach

```
foreach ($access_right in $acl.Access) {
    if (($access_right.FileSystemRights -notmatch $exclude_filesystem_rightss_regex) ){
        foreach($fsr in $access_right.FileSystemRights){
            $file_stream_output.WriteLine(('{0}, {1}, {2}' -f `
                $directory.FullName, 
                $access_right.IdentityReference, 
                $fsr)
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks but it's still all printing to that same line. Also, I guess the " ) " should be placed after " $fsr) ".